# Remove Paragraph Containg specific words(word vba)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I apologize for not having a program to show for my question, but I am in a serious pickle.

I am looking for a vba word program that searches for  specific words and deletes the paragraph those words are in.

The aim of this exercise is to reduce the work load as I am using up to 1million plus words of text.

**EDIT**

I have created the program, could you please help me add a loop, to loop through the whole document?

```
Sub SelectRangeBetween()


    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    'Selection.TypeText Text:="hello"

     ' The Real script
    Dim myrange As Range
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Execute findtext:="From: Research.TA@traditionanalytics.com", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop 'this will initiate the start word
        Set myrange = Selection.Range
        myrange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
        myrange.Start = myrange.Start
        myrange.End = myrange.End + InStr(myrange, "This message has been scanned ") ' this will initiate the end word
        myrange.Select

        'Selection.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, it will search for *TextToSearchFor* and delete the paragraphs where it is found in the same document where you place the code (because I use the `ThisDocument` object). Since you do not specify many details in your question, you will have to modify the `TryMe` sub to fit your needs. Make sure you try it on a test document first! :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub TryMe()
    Call RemoveParagraphs("TextToSearchFor")
End Sub

Sub RemoveParagraphs(psSearchString As String)
    Dim oRng As Range

    Set oRng = ThisDocument.Content

    oRng.Find.Execute FindText:=psSearchString

    While oRng.Find.Found
        oRng.Select
        Selection.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
        Selection.Delete

        Set oRng = ThisDocument.Content
        oRng.Find.Execute FindText:=psSearchString
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Olle, First off wanted to thank you so much, it is perfect. The only issue I am facing is that if the search word is the first word and the paragraph is the next sentence, it will just delete the word. Works great if the word is within the paragraph. also if i wanted to add more than one word could i use the syntax of (jon,paul,sue,jane)? Thanks so much bud.

Comment: Is there a way to add in a phrase which the program will recognize as the ending point, as it deletes everything below the word and some of the information is important.

Comment: Regarding the first problem, it is difficult to say without seeing the actual word document. If the first word is in the same paragraph as the rest of the text they are both supposed to be removed. That is what the `Selection.Expand` line is for. You will have to modify it to select more before running the delete line.

Comment: As for the second question, you could make two searches, one for the first word and then for the ending phrase and make a range or selection from the start of the first range to the end of the second and then delete. The `Range` object has a `Start` and an `End` property, those could be used to make a new range.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head Olle, I am sorry again, but I am terrible at programming in vba word...no idea how to create those ranges. Again, thank you so much for taking the time and effort with me. I have posted an example in the "answer question" part as the words were too long.

Comment: I found a code.But not sure how to loop through the whole document.

Comment: I see you have added an answer to your question, but since it isn't really an answer and it is too big to fit in comments, it should be added to the question. This time, I will add it for you!

Comment: thank you so much, could you help me incorporate a loop into it to loop through the whole document?

Comment: If you look at my code sample you will see that it already has a loop for that in the last part: The `While... Wend` part loops through the document until `.Found` is False. Try to combine my sample with yours and see if you can make it work.

Comment: thanks a lot Olle, let me give it a shot. Thank you for all your help.