# How to delete a section using excel-vba to create a word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, format

Hello and thank you in advance.

I am creating a very complex Word document out of an Excelfile using VBA. It shall be possible to activate something and a text written in a cell shall be transfered to the word document. I got that already done. But if it is not activated the tag "<>" shall be removed, leaving nothing behind. This means that it shall remove not only the text, it shall remove the complete "line". As line might be a section i am not sure if just line is the correct word here.

Right now I find and replace them with "" using:

```
With WordDoc.Content.Find
   .Execute FindText:=ReplacementTextF, ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=2
End With
```

but how can I delete the line/section, too?

**EDIT1:**

Example:

[image]

As the replacement is optional, the user can select which text he wants in the document. Therfore, maybe ReplacementText4 is not needed. So I need to delete the "<< ReplacementText4 >>" and delete the bullet too. This is what I meant by deleting a line/section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Paragraph Containg specific words(word vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017538/remove-paragraph-containg-specific-wordsword-vba)

Comment: You need to provide more information about what this "line" is. Do you mean a paragraph? Or by "section" to you mean a number of paragraphs? Without this kind of information it's impossible to make any suggestions. (BTW you might want to look into the concept of `Bookmarks` as "data targets" in Word instead of using Find/Replace.)

Comment: @Cindy Meister, Thank you for your reply. I tried to make an example and added a screenshot. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: See if this example works: `ReplacementTextF` = "<<ReplacementText1>>^p"` This is adding a paragraph mark to the text. If I'm understanding you correctly, it should do what you describe. If it works, I'll write it up as an Answer...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The question is the same, but the only (and accepted) answer is not an optimal approach at all! Please do *NOT* close as a duplicate of that. Instead, if the OP accepts my suggestion, better to use this as a duplicate of the other! Please retract the duplicate close vote?

Comment: @CindyMeister For me it looked exactly what he was looking for. Nevertheless I retracted my vote to prevent closing it down.

Comment: Seeing what was marked as the Answer, you were right, @Pᴇʜ. My apologies and I'll start the "close as dupe" process!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears as a question about Find/Replace but more correctly is a question about Find, then do something at the site of the found text.  Its a common requirement when the replacement criteria isn't covered by the options of the find/Replace.  The requirement is addressed by the pattern below..

```
    With <Range>
        With .Find
            <setup find criteria for find>
            .wrap = wdFindStop ' This is essential
        End with
        Do while .Find.Found
            <do your actions here>
            <use .duplicate if you want to do something with the found range
            <e.g. to delete the paragraph with the found text
            .duplicate.paragraphs(1).range.delete
            <move the found range to after the end of the found range>
            .collapse direction:=wdcollapseend
            .moveend unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
            .find.execute ' must include this to find next instance

        loop

    End with <range>
```

Translating this pattern into code gives

```
Sub DeleteParasWithText(this_doc As Word.Document, this_find_text As String)

    With this_doc.content
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .text = this_find_text
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchByte = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute

            End With

            Do While .Find.Found
                ' In the OP case we just want to delete the paragraph
                ' containing the found text
                .Duplicate.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Move unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                .Find.Execute
            Loop

        End With
End Sub
```

In presenting this I'd also like to acknowledge @Macropod as I derived this pattern from a number of find/replace examples he has presented in the past.

Comment: It worked smoothly. Thanks a lot for your answer Freeflow. And big thanks for all other participants!