# How to Find text strings (in Word) using a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have a two dimensional array comprised of "trouble" words and phrases in the first dimension and the comments I frequently make in the second dimension. I seem to be lost at how to select the text that matches the first dimension and add the comment using the text from the second dimension. Any ideas?

```
Sub findtrouble()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim oRng As Word.Range



Dim MyArray(1, 4) As String
MyArray(0, 0) = "Trouble0"
MyArray(0, 1) = "Trouble1"
MyArray(0, 2) = "Trouble2"
MyArray(0, 3) = "Trouble3"

MyArray(1, 0) = "Comment0"
MyArray(1, 1) = "Comment1"
MyArray(1, 2) = "Comment2"
MyArray(1, 3) = "Comment3"



For j = 0 To 4
        Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = MyArray(0, j)
        While .Execute
            oRng.Select
            ActiveDocument.Comments.Add oRng, MyArray(1, j)    
        Wend
    End With
    Debug.Print "Find: " & MyArray(0, j) & " add cmt box w/ "; MyArray(1, j)
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to read up on Scripting.Dictionary.  A scripting.dictionary will replace MyArray.  Dictionaries are a data structure that manages key:value pairs.  To get your comment you would use something like my_comment=my_lookup.item(found_text).  (or in your case (ActiveDocument.Comments.Add my_lookup.item(.Range.Text) ).  The oRng.Select you have after the execute is not needed.  The found range can be accessed using just .Range.

Comment: Freeflow's comment aside, what problem is the code you show us having? At a glance, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Cindy -  I got it - I had the review settings to hide comments for some reason..it was working all along! Thanks! I tested the scripting method as well, it works too. Will look more into using scripting dictionaries...they are not something I've ever used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question does insert one comment for me, but that's all. It's because `oRng` isn't being reset. Compare the code in the question to that below.

In this code, after Find.Execute is successful and the comment added the range is collapsed to it endpoint (*after* the found term) then the end extended to the end of the document. In this way, the next time the term is searched it looks only in what follows the first term.

It's also important when looping in Find to set the `Find.Wrap` to `wdFindStop` to avoid going into an "infinite loop" (so that Find doesn't start again at the top of the document).

```
Sub findtrouble()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim oRng As Word.Range

Dim MyArray(1, 4) As String
MyArray(0, 0) = "Trouble0"
MyArray(0, 1) = "Trouble1"
MyArray(0, 2) = "Trouble2"
MyArray(0, 3) = "Trouble3"

MyArray(1, 0) = "Comment0"
MyArray(1, 1) = "Comment1"
MyArray(1, 2) = "Comment2"
MyArray(1, 3) = "Comment3"

For j = 0 To 4
        Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
            .ClearFormatting
            .text = MyArray(0, j)
            .wrap = wdFindStop
            While .Execute
                oRng.Select
                ActiveDocument.Comments.Add oRng, MyArray(1, j)
                oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                oRng.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
            Wend
        End With
    Debug.Print "Find: " & MyArray(0, j) & " add cmt box w/ "; MyArray(1, j)
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Cindy - for some reason, all the comments (Comment0, Comment1, Comment2, etc) get added to the same (the first) comment box. Empty comment boxes get added to the other trouble words, but the associated comment ends up placed in the first comment in the document. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

As per @Cindy Meisters' comment the posted code does work (even with the indexing error in the for loop).  The code below is the same rewritten to use a scripting.dictionary

```
Sub testfindtrouble()
    findtrouble ActiveDocument.Range
End Sub
Sub findtrouble(this_range As Word.Range)
Dim my_lookup       As scripting.Dictionary
Dim my_troubles     As Variant
Dim my_trouble      As Variant
Dim my_range        As Word.Range

' see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317548/how-to-delete-a-section-using-excel-vba-to-create-a-word-document/53322166?noredirect=1#comment93559248_53322166
    Set my_lookup = New scripting.Dictionary

    With my_lookup

        .Add key:="Trouble0", item:="Comment0"
        .Add key:="Trouble1", item:="Comment1"
        .Add key:="Trouble2", item:="Comment2"
        .Add key:="Trouble3", item:="Comment3"

    End With

    my_troubles = my_lookup.Keys

    ' Avoid the off by 1 error (j=0 to 4 is 5 items not the 4 you declared in the array
    For Each my_trouble In my_troubles

        Set my_range = this_range.Duplicate

        With my_range

            With .Find

                .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
                .ClearFormatting
                .text = my_trouble
                .Execute

            End With

            Do While .Find.Found

                 Debug.Print "Find: " & my_trouble & " add cmt box w/ "; my_lookup.item(my_trouble)
                .Comments.Add .Duplicate, my_lookup.item(my_trouble)
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Move unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                .Find.Execute

            Loop

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```